# ADF log analytics - how to correlate multiple pipelines

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have been doing some experimentation and for an ADF log in Log Analytics the correlation ID appears to be a copy of the Pipeline RunId.  The TriggerId appears to be blank.

I have a pipelines that call other pipelines.

```
ScheduledTrigger -> Pipeline 1 -> activity 1 execute pipeline(pipeline 2)
                               -> activity 2 execute pipeline(pipeline 3)
```

I'd like a single ID that enables me to find all pipelines and activities that were run from the parent trigger.  I thought that would be in the correlation ID or the Trigger ID.

I know I can solve this by passing the trigger ID from the @trigger() object as a parameter through the stack of pipelines but wondered if I am missing some trick to get this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Just closing this - I did what I anticipated I needed to do.
The top most parent copies the pipeline's RunId and passes it as a parameter to all child pipelines.  All child pipelines pass on this same RunId to their children (not their own RunID).

When I call stored procedures or external resources (like web or function), I pass this same RunID as a required parameter.  This way there is a consistent correlation ID available to all children whether they be pipelines, SPs or external calls.

I maintain the name "RunID" all the way through to log analytics from any component and therefore can easily get a full picture of what went on.  Whiel this is a bit of overhead, it has saved hours of debugging when something goes wrong across multiple ADF, functions, logic apps, web calls, SP calls, etc because they are all tied together by this RunID.

Hope this helps.
Mark.

Comment: Yup! Makes sense. It is amazing that MS is not maintaining a proper correlation ID between pipeline runs...