# Is there any correlation between PipelineId and CorelationId in Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics

Is there any relationship between pipelinerunid and correlationId in ADF v2?

We have enabled LogAnalytics in ADF v2 and now we need to backtrack a Pipeline run for which I have its PipelineRunid.

So how should I filter out the log data based on PipelineRunId?

There are some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034373/adf-log-analytics-how-to-correlate-multiple-pipelines) wherein they have mentioned that CorrelationId and PipelineId are same :

But that is not the case.

So wanted the help on the same

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: Hi @Pratick Somaiya, If my answer is helpful for you, can you please vote or accept(mark) it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any relationship between pipelinerunid and correlationId in ADF v2?**

PipelineID is the ID of the pipeline run.

CorrelationId is the unique ID for tracking a particular request.

[image]

Ref: [Monitor and Alert Data Factory by using Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor)

**How should I filter out the log data based on PipelineRunId?**

When we open the logs, we query the log tables `ADFPipelineRun` and `ADFActivityRun` by column `PipelineRunId`/`RunID`.

For example:

[image]

For more details, you could ref: [Tutorial: Get started with Log Analytics queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/get-started-portal).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply :)
But the use case is to fetch the username who has triggered the pipeline manually.
In case if we use ADF pipeline run , we do not get the eventinitiatedby details.

But when we query the activitylogs based on the resourceuri , we got all details including corelationid of that execution except pipelinerunid.

So how should we link up the activitylog with the pipelinerunid?